# Is there a way to edit a javascript function back to the original?

Tags: javascript, function, fiddler

So I had this code here which overwrites the default canvas.toDataURL() function and makes it return something different.

```js
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL = function () {
    return "data:image/png;base64," + thing;
}
```

And I was thinking if there was any way to restore the toDataURL function back to how it functions normally either through updating it again or deleting the lines of code?

So I was thinking of executing some code like:

```js
HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL = function () {
    //original code for toDataURL
}
```

This code is for a page that already exists on the internet so this line of code is run before I can delete it.

**Things I have tried:**

1. Using Google Chrome's Developer Tools > Sources > Deleting the line from the javascript code > Ctrl + S to save the javascript > Trying to call the function .toDataURL(), however, toDataURL() still performs the modified version rather than what I want which is the original version.

I suspect this is because I am not properly saving the changes as the changes to the toDataURL() function are in an external Javascript file.

2. I have also looked into using fiddler 4 with google chrome, but I'm not having much luck on that end, despite having created breakpoints every time a javascript file should be added. This is with the intention of stopping the execution of the code, giving me time to edit the javascript file before it runs.

I have created breakpoints in fiddler 4 by making the following changes for the code in the custom rules:

```
    static function OnBeforeResponse(oSession: Session) {
        if (m_Hide304s && oSession.responseCode == 304) {
            oSession["ui-hide"] = "true";
        }
        if (oSession.oResponse.headers.ExistsAndContains("Content-Type", "javascript")){
            oSession["x-breakresponse"]="reason is JScript"; 
        }
    }
```

The error which occurs is Google Chrome does not pause on a breakpoint like it is supposed to once I load the page which loads the changes for the toDataURL() in an external JS file thus, I cannot edit the Javascript files to delete the lines of code before they are executed.

The breakpoints still happen but at the wrong times for example when I click on the Google Chrome address bar.

And despite adding a breakpoint the link itself for the specific external javascript file to fiddler with the command:

```
bup https://url/changeFunction.min.js
```

The breakpoint does not happen, thus, not giving me the chance to edit the file.

Comment: you should store the old function.

Comment: @appleapple I would love to I typed HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL into the console, but what it gives as an output is something which is not a function I can copy instead something like  toDataURL()
​
length: 0
​
name: "toDataURL"
​
<prototype>: ()
​​
apply: apply()
​​​
length: 2
​​​
name: "apply"
​​​
<prototype>: function ()
​​
arguments:

Comment: can´t you just remove your overwrite? also when i enter into console it shows `ƒ toDataURL() { [native code] }` try it on another website

Comment: That *is* a function. Just do `let origToDataURL = HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL;` And when you want it back, `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.toDataURL = origToDataURL`.

Comment: @johnSmith this is because this is for an external website that already has this javascript code which is why I can't remove the overwrite because they have already overwritten it. I've tried it on another website and I get the same result in Google Chrome.

Comment: @trincot apologies I was wrong there, that is a function. Also, that solution seems to work, only thing it's missing is you need to make a breakpoint before the line executes in the browser and you can't use let, instead you need to use var origToDataURL if you're doing it from the browser. Other than that it's perfect thank you!